# Error in drawing a curve in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw the curve y(x-2)^2-x(y-8)^2=0. This is the code that I have worked

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,yscale=1]
\begin{axis}[axis x line=center, axis y
line=center,xmin=-40, ymin=-25, xmax=20, ymax=30, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
height=9cm, width=7cm, xlabel style={right}, ylabel style={above}]
\addplot[id=curve, color=red, raw gnuplot, samples=50] function{ f(x,y) =
y*(x-2)^2-x*(y-8)^2; 
set xrange [-40:20]; 
set yrange [-25:30]; 
set view 0,0;
set isosample 1000,1000; 
%set size square; 
set cont base; 
set cntrparam levels
incre 0,0.1,0; unset surface; 
splot f(x,y) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am getting the following curve[image]

But there is no gap near y=10. How to do so.

Comment: You may solve x as a function of y. It will be something like f(x) ± √(g(x)). So you can plot the two branches around (2, 8).

Comment: on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ , try this `size(8cm);
import contour;
real f(real x, real y){return y*(x-2)^2-x*(y-8)^2;}
guide[][] thegraphs = contour(f,
a=(0,0), b=(10,15), new real[] {0},500,operator..);
draw(thegraphs[0]);
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Ti*k*Z approach.

First, if we solve the equation for `y` (or for `x` as Symbol 1 suggested), we'll have

[image]

So we can declare two functions:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{aux}{1}{\pgfmathparse{#1+12+4/#1}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{myf}{2}{\pgfmathparse{0.5*(aux(#1)+#2*sqrt(aux(#1)*aux(#1)-256))}}
```

The first one is for the repeated part. The second, the function we want to plot, takes two arguments: the variable and the sign (-1,+1) for the plus/minus before the square root.

And now we only have to plot the function avoiding the difficult points (also plotted) where the different branches cross one another. This is to prevent the annoying precision errors, you know:

> Package PGF Math Error: I cannot calculate the square-root of the negative number...

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{aux}{1}{\pgfmathparse{#1+12+4/#1}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{myf}{2}{\pgfmathparse{0.5*(aux(#1)+#2*sqrt(aux(#1)*aux(#1)-256))}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,thick,samples=100,line cap=round]
\pgfmathsetmacro\px{-0.5*(28+sqrt(768))} % -27.8564 copy-pasted from the generated pdf
% axes and labels
\draw[-latex] (-40,0) -- (20,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-25) -- (0,30) node [above] {$y$};
\foreach\i in {-40,-20,20}
  \draw (\i,0.3) --+ (0,-0.6) node [below] {$\i$};
\foreach\i in {-20,-10,10,20,30}
  \draw (0.3,\i) --+ (-0.6,0) node [left]  {$\i$};
% right, descending branch
\draw[red] plot[domain=0.2:1.9] (\x,{myf(\x, 1)}) -- plot[domain=2.1:20]      (\x,{myf(\x,-1)});
% right, ascending branch
\draw[red] (0,0) --
           plot[domain=0.1:1.9] (\x,{myf(\x,-1)}) -- plot[domain=2.1:20]      (\x,{myf(\x, 1)});
% left branch
\draw[red] plot[domain=-40:\px] (\x,{myf(\x, 1)}) -- plot[domain=\px-0.1:-40] (\x,{myf(\x,-1)});
% points
\filldraw[red] (0,0)    circle (2mm);
\filldraw[red] (2,8)    circle (2mm) node[black,right] {$(2,8)$};
\filldraw[red] (\px,-8) circle (2mm) node[black,right] {$(\px,-8)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked now.